# Where is the flaw in my algorithm for finding the max element of an array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

In order to feel smarter, I'm trying to write **every** algorithm recursively, even when a non-recursive solution is more readable and efficient (as in the case of "Hello, World!" hehe). I'm starting out by doing this with a simple max function

```
function max ( arr )
{
     max_in_bounds(arr,0,arr.length);
}

function max_in_bounds ( A, i, j )
{
      // finds the max element in the range of 
    // indices [i, j) of the array A
    var diff = j - i;
    if ( diff === 1) 
    {
          return A[i];  
    }
    else if ( diff > 1 ) 
    {
             return Math.max(A[i], max_in_bounds(A,i+1,A.length));      
    }
}

var my_array = [1, 4, -3, 69]; 
console.log(max(my_array)); // Should print 69
```

but for some reason I'm getting `undefined` and I'm trying to figure out why. Any hints?

Comment: You left out `return` from the `max()` function.

Comment: You can call `Math.max` with array using `Math.max.apply(Math, my_array)`

Comment: `In order to feel smarter, I'm trying to write **every** algorithm recursively` - MMD. Wait - is that _trying to write a recursive version of **every** algorithm_, or _trying recursively to write, trying recursively to write recursively, recursively trying recursively to write recursively …_?

Comment: @jcubic: Why suggest `Math.max` when OP explicitly wants to implement the algorithms him/herself for learning purposes? OP is using it, but I'm also not sure why, given the initial question :/

Comment: In `function max_in_bounds(A, i, j)`, the third parameter to the recursive call `max_in_bounds(A, i+1, A.length)` looks fishy.

Comment: if you want to feel smarter, then please write all of these algorithms to consume less than linear stack space.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no return in the function:

```
function max ( arr ){
     return max_in_bounds(arr,0,arr.length);
}
```

and therefore it returns `undefined`. Also I hope you are writing these every recursion algorithms only for the learning purposes.